# how to change the data loaded from a local json file in swift and present the changed datat simultaneously in different pages

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I was trying to parse a local JSON file into my own struct, it work well. Now I want to change some values like `DOUBAN_VOTES` in the array. I don't know how to do that and how to show this changed data simultaneously on different pages.

the problem is when I'm trying to pass a new value to my movieData, I didn't get it changed. for an example: the `DOUBAN_VOTES` is 3000, and I add it to 3001 at `mypage.swift` , but on another page, it still shows as 3000

**my struct**

```
import Foundation


struct Movie:Codable {
    var MOVIE_ID:String
    var NAME:String
    var ALIAS:String?
    var ACTORS:String?
    var COVER:String?
    var DIRECTORS:String?
    var DOUBAN_SCORE:String?
    var DOUBAN_VOTES:String?
    var GENRES:String?
    var IMDB_ID:String?
    var LANGUAGES:String?
    var MINS:String?
    var OFFICIAL_SITE:String?
    var REGIONS:String?
    var RELEASE_DATE:String?
    var SLUG:String?
    var STORYLINE:String?
    var TAGS:String?
    var YEAR:String?
    var ACTOR_IDS:String?
    var DIRECTOR_IDS:String?
    var isFavered:Bool = false
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case MOVIE_ID, NAME,ALIAS,ACTORS,COVER,DIRECTORS,DOUBAN_SCORE
        case DOUBAN_VOTES,GENRES,IMDB_ID,LANGUAGES,MINS,OFFICIAL_SITE
        case REGIONS,RELEASE_DATE,SLUG,STORYLINE,TAGS,YEAR,ACTOR_IDS,DIRECTOR_IDS
    }
    
}
class moviedata: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myMovieData:[Movie] = Bundle.main.decode(filename:"movieData1.json")
}

extension Bundle{
    func decode<T:Codable>(filename:String) -> T {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil),
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
              let getResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
              else { fatalError("no data")}
        return getResponse
    }
}
```

**my SwiftUI file: I want to pass the value to the array when click button "confirm"**

```
import SwiftUI

struct myPage: View {
    //@State var movieData: [Movie] = []
    @ObservedObject var movieData=moviedata()
    @State private var index = 0
    @State private var nf = NumberFormatter()
    @State private var temp:Int=0;
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Text(movieData.myMovieData[index].NAME)
            Text("vote: \(temp)")
            
            //Text(verbatim: vote)
            Button("next"){
                index=index+1
            }
            Button("add"){
                temp = temp + 1
                
            }
            Button("comfirm"){
                movieData.myMovieData[index].DOUBAN_VOTES=String(temp)
            }
//here I want to change the data
            
        }.onChange(of: index, perform: { value in
           
                temp=nf.number(from: movieData.myMovieData[index].DOUBAN_VOTES ?? "0") as! Int
           
        })
        .onAppear{
            temp=nf.number(from: movieData.myMovieData[index].DOUBAN_VOTES ?? "0") as! Int
        }

    }
}

struct myPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        myPage()
    }
}
```

**my json file**

```
[
{
"MOVIE_ID":"27021694",
"NAME":"耶尔玛",
"ALIAS":"",
"ACTORS":"比莉·派佩/布伦丹·考威尔/约翰·麦克米兰",
"COVER":"",
"DIRECTORS":"西蒙·斯通",
"DOUBAN_SCORE":"8.2",
"DOUBAN_VOTES":"187",
"GENRES":"剧情/戏曲",
"IMDB_ID":"tt6847880",
"LANGUAGES":"英语",
"MINS":"0",
"OFFICIAL_SITE":"http://ntlive.nationaltheatre.org.uk/productions/ntlout22-yerma",
"REGIONS":"英国",
"RELEASE_DATE":"2017/8/31",
"SLUG":"72FZ3FZ3b",
"STORYLINE":"A young woman is driven to the unthinkable by her desperate desire to have a child in Simon Stone’s radical production of Lorca’s achingly powerful masterpiece.",
"TAGS":"NTLive/女性/舞台剧/戏剧/英国/英国国家剧院现场/BilliePiper/NTL",
"YEAR":"2017",
"ACTOR_IDS":"比莉·派佩:1049548|Maureen Beattie:|布伦丹·考威尔:1022987|约翰·麦克米兰:1319678|Charlotte Randle:|Thalissa Teixeira:",
"DIRECTOR_IDS":"西蒙·斯通:1336274"
}
]
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is with the current code.

Comment: I agree, your question isn't clear, but a couple of style points - Why are all of your properties optionals?  If you are going to use `CodingKeys` to change the property names, you should change them to Swift style camelCase (ie. `genres` not `GENRES` and `actorIds` not `ACTOR_IDS` etc).  Also, don't use `try ?` when decoding.  Use `do/try/catch` so that you can print any errors.

Comment: the problem is when I'm trying to pass a new value to my `movieData`, I didn't get it changed. for example:  the `DOUBAN_VOTES` is 3000, and I add it to 3001 at `mypage.swift` , but in another page it still shows as 3000

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi, I've updated my answer with part of my json file, I tried not to use optional properties but then I can't get the json decoded

Comment: Which is why you don't use `try ?` - If you catch the `error` and `print` it you will get a message that tells you what is wrong with your decoding.

Comment: How do you pass/access the data in "the other page" - If you simply fetch the data again from the bundle it won't have changed.  You need to pass the object you have loaded and modified

Comment: I think didn't fetch the data twice using `ObservableObject` and ` ObservedObject`  but it didn't work. I don't know whether there is s way to update the json file or other ways to change and present my data.

Comment: If the JSON is local why don't you provide a more suitable format? And please conform to the Swift naming convention. Structs/classes/enums should be named UpperCamelCase and variables/functions/enum cases lowerCamelCase. And in each of your latest three questions you are told not to use `try?`, you should take those advices. And again if the JSON is local declaring all properties   carelessly as optional is very bad practice because **you** know exactly the data.

Comment: There is some kind of dire deadline I'm facing so I did change `try?` when it works not bad.  I will try to use the `do/try/catch` later, thanks for the advice!

Comment: the JSON file is downloaded from the Internet and it contains thousands of data, so I didn't change the name style

Comment: That's what `CodingKeys` are for.

Comment: Since you are using SwiftUI you can make use of an @EnvironmentObject to share data between multiple views, see [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a function "confirm" in your "ViewModel" (aka `moviedata`):

```
func confirm(movieID: String, votes: Int)
```

Even better, manage the number of votes in the view model, rather than in the view:

```
func upVote(movieID: String)
func downVote(movieID: String)
```

These functions mutate the view model's internal state and in turn mutates the published variable `myMovieData`.

The change will be immediately reflected in the views which observe it.

In your button action, simply call this confirm function:

```
    ...
    Button("comfirm") {
        let movie = movieData.myMovieData[index]
        movieData.confirm(movieID: movie.MOVIE_ID, votes: temp)
    }
```

**Final notes**

Please fix typos and apply common Swift style for class, struct and variable names.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I don't know how to handle the type problem, because the data in my JSON file are all string. When I decode the json file I have to use string type for `vote`  When I am trying to add number to `vote`(string) in the upVote function  using `Int(DOUBAN_VOTES)= Int(DOUBAN_VOTES)+1`, it shows an error as  
 Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value

Comment: @Hannah You can convert any Int value to a string, simply: `"\(intValue)"`. And vice  versa: `let value: Int? = Int("123")` - which _may_ return `.none` (`nil`) if the string cannot be expressed as a value of Int.